# jQuery .load() not woking for the Windows' version of Chrome

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.choices a img').click(function(e) {  
var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' .con_cen2';  
$('.con_cen').html('loading...').load('signup.html');
e.preventDefault();
})
});
```

This works on Windows, Mac, and Linux both locally and remotely for every browser I’ve tested except for Chrome on Windows.  It works on Safari 4 for my 10-year-old Mac, it works for WebOS on my palm pre, it even works for Chrome on a Linux box.

But Chrome for Windows won’t allow it either locally or remotely (using my hosting company’s servers).  Locally it just links to 'signup.html'.  Remotely it gives a 404.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Google tries to do some strange things that are supposed to be "user friendly" but end up breaking things.  Try under options->under the hood, disabling "Predict Network actions".  You might also try the latest build of chromium to see if you can reproduce the same problem there.

You try fiddling with some of the other options there, even clearing cache may do something.

Comment: Thanks, that did help.  I disabled Chrome's DOM sniffer and it worked.  I wonder what that had to do with this?